# How to get the field type name in firestore python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

We have a dataset in firestore. We would like to find the field type of an existing data. Our configration is Python 3.7 in google app engine standard.

Answer (score 0):

Get the field object using get(). Then use the python type function to get the name of the class.

```
document_col_ref = db.collection( u'collection_key' )            
document_query   = document_col_ref.where(field1', u'==', field_value)            
docs               = document_query.stream()
            
docs_array = []
for doc in docs:
    docs_array.append(doc)

first_doc = docs_array[0]            
field_obj   = first_doc.get('field_name')
field_type  = type(field_obj)            
field_type_value    = field_type.__name__
```